# JSONP - return HTML

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I'm using JSONP with code:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost:8080/pool/main/?pool=abcd",
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    success:function(response){
        $('#pool').append(response);
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("ERROR");
        },
});
</script>
```

**I have to user JSONP, becouse i need ajax cross domain**

In my application response from "`http://localhost:8080/pool/main/?pool=abcd`" is HTML code.

I wanted to display this code in my page, but there is an error, because as i assume, i can't return html.

ERROR - i mean - it produce me this code `error:function(){
            alert("ERROR");
            }`, but i see in firebug that the response from my page `http://localhost:8080/pool/main/?pool=abcd` is ok. But secoundly. i don't know how to put the response to html element.

My question is - CAN I or I CAN'T.

If i can - how to do this ?

Comment: "an error" is *never* a good error description. Please describe what goes wrong, what the exact error message is that you get, etc.

Comment: If it's HTML, then it isn't JSONP :-?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), you need to generate a piece of scripts calling a method with returned data. If you want to get a piece of HTML, your url should output code like this:

```
callFunction("<div>abc</div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can display the response HTML text on your page. You just have to add the response value to any HTML element like `<div>` or `<span>`.

You can also do it with following code.

```
var URL = "http://localhost:8080/pool/main/?pool=abcd";
new Request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: URL,
    assign: 'true',
    onComplete: function(responseText) {
        $('#pool').innerHTML = responseText;
    }
}).send();
```

Here your responseText will be set to the `#pool` element.

Comment: But in this example it is not JSONP ?

Answer (score 0):

yes. JSONP is datatype where response is sent as an argument to a function. Response accessible in that function.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost:8080/pool/main/?pool=abcd",
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    success:function(response){
     callFunction(response);
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("ERROR");
        },
});

function callFunction(data){
 $('#pool').innerHTML = data;
}
```

Comment: What is a difference if I will use use `callFunction(response);` instead just `$('#pool').innerHTML = data;` ?

Comment: Makes no sense of adding another function to achieve same result w/o it